# MaaS - juju boostrap and ssh not found

Tags: ssh, juju, maas

today I want to `juju boostrap` so I do ssh-keygen and get this

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/hsf/.ssh/id_rsa): key
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): ubuntu
Enter same passphrase again: ubuntu
Your identification has been saved in key.
Your public key has been saved in key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
7e:d2:df:66:f5:2f:92:02:ad:10:67:b7:10:cd:33:03 hsf@ubuntu-server
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|        E+       |
|        . *      |
|         . +     |
|      . + .      |
|       +S+ .     |
|      ....o     .|
|       .ooo  . ..|
|        .o..o.+ .|
|           ..+..o|
+-----------------+
```

Then I copy my public key in key.pub is like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC89zkec0YhwYuUmjB6oxmLGmzH2nCvJMF0mjigodxN$
```

To the maas dashboard : press "Add SSH key" and copy and add key.

So now I want to bootstrap and I get this:

```
2012-08-27 13:02:02,923 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
2012-08-27 13:02:05,935 ERROR Failed to launch machine /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-3c4b1752-f031-11e1-bd44-001185e67955/; attempting to release.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/maas/launch.py", line 44, in start_machine
    cloud_init = self._create_cloud_init(machine_id, zookeepers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/common/launch.py", line 95, in _create_cloud_init
    cloud_init.add_ssh_key(get_user_authorized_keys(config))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/common/utils.py", line 84, in get_user_authorized_keys
    raise LookupError("SSH authorized/public key not found.")
LookupError: SSH authorized/public key not found.
SSH authorized/public key not found.
2012-08-27 13:02:11,969 ERROR SSH authorized/public key not found.
```

I don't know what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things you're doing wrong:

1. You don't need to put an SSH key into MAAS when using Juju, Juju will
   handle all that for you.

2.

> Enter file in which to save the key (/home/hsf/.ssh/id_rsa): key

Let it write the file in the default location. Then Juju will find it and use
it.